# boto3 create_vpn_gateway() method is not supporting AmazonSideAsn attribute

Tags: boto3

I'm trying to create AWS Virtual Private Gateway with Custom ASN number using boto3.

```
ec2_conn.create_vpn_gateway(Type='ipsec.1',AmazonSideAsn=64512)
```

But this is giving error as below

```
ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "AmazonSideAsn", must be one of: AvailabilityZone, Type, DryRun
```

Is AmazonSideAsn is supported in boto version 3 (boto3), if supported am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You probably just need to update botocore: `pip install --upgrade botocore boto3`

Comment: Hi @JordonPhillips, thanks it worked. Previously I've installed the latest boto3(1.4.7) version but it didn't worked. The botocore version was 1.7.35. Now the version of botocore=1.7.36 and boto3=1.4.7.